# How do I loop functions correctly with set Interval?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, setinterval

I am building a background image slideshow with javascript and CSS. I need it to zoom in images, zoom out, and switch images. I have three functions but they don't work properly. I tried to loop these functions with set intervals, but it only works properly the first time. Why is this happening? Is there a better alternative?

```
var i = 1
function zoomin(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1.2)").css("transition", "6s")
  setInterval(()=>zoomout(), 6000)
}
function zoomout(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1.15)").css("transition", "2s")
  setInterval(()=>changeImg(), 2000)
}
function changeImg(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1)").css("transition", "2s")
  i+=1
  if (i==1){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image1.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i==2){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image2.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i===3){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image3.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i==4){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image4.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i==5){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image5.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i==6){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image6.jpg)")
    return ;
  }else if (i==7){
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image7.jpg)")
    return ; 
  }
  setInterval(()=>zoomin(), 2000)
}
```

Comment: What's the ideal scenario/outcome you would like to have? Does it need to loop 7 times? Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setInterval()` isn't the correct time function to use in this case, you will also have a logic error due to where you increment `i`. There is also `setTimeout()`. As said in the comments in the code (along with some other tips in your code), the difference of setTimeout and setInterval is that setInterval does the function every n milliseconds, while setTimeout calls the function after n milliseconds.

```
var i = 1;
function zoomin(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1.2)").css("transition", "6s")
  setTimeout(zoomout, 6*1000);
}
function zoomout(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1.15)").css("transition", "2s")
  setTimeout(changeImg, 2*1000);
}
function changeImg(){
  $(".bg").css("transform","scale(1)").css("transition", "2s")
  $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(homeimg/image"+i+".jpg)"); /* You can delete all
 those if statements by just using the index for each image*/

  i = (i+1) % 8; /* [Increment i after setting the css, otherwise you 
will never edit the first one] 
[Also increment and set to modulus of seven, so that the index will loop and not go 
out of bounds i.e. 9,10,11..., will only stay between 1-7]*/

  setTimeout(zoomin, 2*1000); /* Difference of setTimeout and setInterval is that setInterval
 does the function every n milliseconds, while setTimeout calls the function after n milliseconds*/
}

changeImg(); // Call the function to execute the loop
```